# How can I create dynamic assemblies and save them to disk using .NET 5 or later?

Tags: .net, reflection.emit

I am trying to use AssemblyBuilder to create dynamic assemblies and save them in .NET 5,6,7

```
// Create the dynamic assembly
var builder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("DynamicAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
```

It seems `AssemblyBuilderAccess` now lacks the `RunAndSave` value, probably it is intentional to prevent persisting dynamically generated code (or was the deeply Windows dependent code of emit the issue?), anyway, I am wondering that there is an other mode or workaround.

**Question**

How can I create dynamic assemblies and save them to disk using .NET 5 or later?

Comment: According to the docs, you should use MetadataBuilder

Comment: Use https://github.com/Lokad/ILPack/. It's mentioned in [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/15704) about lacking support for AssemblyBuilder.Save

Comment: @JL0PD, indeed, it is mentioned, however that is only a backup plan to use a third party lib

Comment: There are 2 ways to save then. 1. Reimplement library, it's build on top of System.Reflection.Metadata. 2. Upgrade to net8

Answer (score 0):

There is no official implementation yet, but it looks like there will be one:

- .NET 8: [Add persist able AssemblyBuilder implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/83988)
- .NET 9: [Tracking issue for remaining AssemblyBuilder.Save](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/92975)

There are also some other alternatives:

- [AssemblyBuilder.Save()](https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/tree/feature/assembly-builder-save)
- [ILPack](https://github.com/Lokad/ILPack)